# How can i retrieve devenv.exe path for a vspackage installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, devenv, vspackage

I'm following this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb458038.aspx to create a VsPackage Setup. In the part of the creation of an installer class appears a reference to this location in the registry "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VS\EnvironmentPath" where it says that contains the devenv.exe location. I explore the registry and that location doesn't exist.
What is the correct location of the devenv.exe path? I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sharing my code. It’s working for me.

```
String path = GetDevenvPath("9.0"); // For VS 2008 
Or
String path = GetDevenvPath("10.0");  For VS 2010

private String GetDevenvPath(String vsVersion)
{
   String vsInstallPath = (String)Registry.GetValue(String.Format("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\{0}", vsVersion), "InstallDir", "");
   return vsInstallPath + "devenv.exe";
}
```

Comment: Test in Win7 64 bits and XP 32bits ? VS 32 bits and VS 64 bits ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to access `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VS\EnvironmentPath` on 32bit machines and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VS\EnvironmentPath` on 64bit machines.

If you write a 32bit program that reads the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VS\EnvironmentPath` you will be automatically redirected to `Wow6432Node` on 64bit machines by Windows.